# GLMM optimised with CG gives empty warning, diagnose() finds no problem

Tags: optimization, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, glmmtmb

I am running the following code for a ZINB GLMM, using the glmmTMB package in R:

```
glmm_complex <- glmmTMB(
  count ~ group
  + season_cut * group
  + region * group
  + (1 | bird_ID),
  data = df_noDT,
  family = nbinom2,
  ziformula = ~.,
  offset = offset,
  control = glmmTMBControl(
    optimizer = optim,
    optArgs = list(method = "CG"),
    rank_check = "adjust"
  )
)
```

I chose "CG" as optimiser because and the estimate and standard errors in the zi-component were very high for the parameter value "early" in season_cut. Uisng this optimiser brings the values lower levels:

```
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                     -3.3384     0.8890  -3.755 0.000173 ***
grouppost_mahd:season_cutearly   1.4880     3.2336   0.460 0.645403
grouppre_mahd:season_cutearly    1.1148     3.1612   0.353 0.724353
```

But it also outputs:

```
Warning message:
In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
  Model convergence problem; . See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

There is no explanation to the convergence problem, and running diagnose() gives me:

```
model looks OK!
```

Running the model on "L-BFGS-B" gives me an equally cryptic convergence message:

```
Warning message:
In finalizeTMB(TMBStruc, obj, fit, h, data.tmb.old) :
  Model convergence problem; NEW_X. See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

Besides brief discussions in [these](https://github.com/gagneurlab/OUTRIDER/issues/7) [two](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-June/354614.html) sources, I couldn't find anything to NEW_X (it's not in the vignette). I tried setting maxit = 20000 as read in the Github link, but it didn't change anything.

**What do the convergence warnings from CG and L-BFGS-B mean?**

Comment: Hi Barbara. Welcome to CV. Would you be able to trim it down a bit? I think it is a bit long for a single post; if possible could you bifurcate the current one into two smaller posts so that it may be easy for a potential answerer to attend to your queries?

Comment: Thank you for the input @User1865345 and sorry, I was criticised in other communities for lack of info. I'll trim it down!

Comment: Although it is not my field of expertise, I think it ia fairly detailed. Just that it seems to be too dense for a single post.